# sorting list of lists and getting indices in unsorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting

These are the logical steps that I need to perform on my list of lists

```
a = [[5,2],[7,4],[0,3]]
```

1. sort the list of lists in such a way that the output looks something like

   ```
   7,5,4,3,2,0
   ```
2. take the coordinates of the sorted elements in the original list, which in this case should produce as output

   ```
   (1,0)
   (0,0)
   (1,1)
   (2,1)
   (0,1)
   (2,0)
   ```

I tried using of `sort, sorted` and `argwhere` in different ways but I am not getting sensible results, I guess first of all because `sort` and `sorted` can sort a list following only one axis at a time

Comment: Do you only want to output the indices, or do you also want to output the values (i.e 7,5,4,3,2,0)?

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't need to output the values, but I do need to be able to get them for further calculations

Comment: what about duplicates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will work for a list of lists. The internal lists don't have to be the same length.

At each level we iterate over a list using `enumerate` to get the list item and its index. At the top level, each item is another list, and the inner loop iterates over each of those lists to get their indices and values, storing the indices (as a tuple) in a tuple that also contains the value. We then sort the resulting list of tuples (`b`) on the values, and then split it using `zip` into a tuple of all the indices and a tuple of the values.

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[5, 2], [7, 4], [0, 3]]

b = [((i, j), v) for i, t in enumerate(a) for j, v in enumerate(t)]
b.sort(key=itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
print(b)
coords, vals = zip(*b)
print(vals)
print(coords)
```

**output**

```
[((1, 0), 7), ((0, 0), 5), ((1, 1), 4), ((2, 1), 3), ((0, 1), 2), ((2, 0), 0)]
(7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0)
((1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0))
```

Comment: Aka the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: @Bergi Well spotted. :) It's rarely necessary to use it explicitly in Python (although I guess any use of a key function with sort / sorted is effectively a  Schwartzian sort under the hood), so it was kinda fun to have a good excuse to use it here.

Answer (score 8):

Create a dictionary with the keys as the actual coordinates and the values as the numbers themselves, like this

```
>>> a = [[5, 2], [7, 4], [0, 3]]
>>> positions = {
...     (idx1, idx2): col
...     for idx1, row in enumerate(a)
...     for idx2, col in enumerate(row)
... }
>>> positions
{(0, 1): 2, (2, 0): 0, (0, 0): 5, (1, 0): 7, (1, 1): 4, (2, 1): 3}
```

Now, sort the keys (coordinates) of `positions` based on their values, like this

```
>>> sorted(positions, key=positions.get, reverse=True)
[(1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a series of list comprehensions and `zip` blocks, although the readability suffers:

```
n, idxs = zip(*sorted(zip([i for sl in a for i in sl], [(col, row) for col in range(len(a)) for row in range(len(a[col]))]), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))

print n, idxs
>>> (7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0) ((1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0))
```

If you need a dict, just replace the `zip(*..)` layer with `dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Numpy`, which is pretty much faster than regular python code when you are dealing with larger arrays:

```
In [21]: a = np.array([[5,2],[7,4],[0,3]])
In [22]: x, y = np.unravel_index((-a).argsort(axis=None), a.shape)

In [23]: indices = np.column_stack((x, y))

In [24]: indices
Out[24]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 0]])

In [25]: a[x, y]
Out[25]: array([7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0])
```

Comment: and all the others, what is the best way to use, if I then need to use the first two indices [1,0], [0,0] (for example). I mean: consider that I need to then extract a[1][0] and a[0,0], how can I do?

Comment: @johnhenry Checkout the update. It's a more general way which gives you the sorted array with a simple indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the list and then use it to sort and find indices.

```
a = [[5,2],[7,4],[0,3]]
c = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)
b = sorted(c, reverse=True)
for i in b:
    print c.index(i)/2, c.index(i)%2
```

Output:

```
1 0 
0 0
1 1
2 1
0 1
2 0
```

Comment: This won't work so well if there are any repeated values. Also, it assumes that the inner lists will always have exactly 2 items.

Comment: @PM2Ring unless OP clarifies i guess inner lists with exactly 2 items is a fair assumption.

Comment: Fair enough. But the point about repeated values still stands. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring yes again OP needs to clarify if he wants the first position always or real positions in case of duplicates !!! newaz thats easy to fix :)