# Python - Selecting elements that sum up to the 68% of the cumulative sum in a 2D list

Tags: python, sorting

I have my values in a two dimensional list.

```
a = [[5,2],[7,4],[0,3]]
```

Thanks to the answers to this question 
[sorting list of lists and getting indices in unsorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358056/sorting-list-of-lists-and-getting-indices-in-unsorted-list/)
I managed to sort them in decreasing order and I got the coordinates of the values in the previous list.

```
from operator import itemgetter

b = [((i, j), v) for i, t in enumerate(a) for j, v in enumerate(t)]
b.sort(key=itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
print(b)
coords, vals = zip(*b)
print(vals)
print(coords)
```

output:

```
[((1, 0), 7), ((0, 0), 5), ((1, 1), 4), ((2, 1), 3), ((0, 1), 2), ((2, 0), 0)]
(7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0)
((1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0))
```

Now I need to first of all calculate the total cumulative sum of the elements, which I perform by using

```
cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(a)
```

Then I need to start summing the ordered elements, until they reach a certain value, which is 68% of `cumulative_sum`. In this case, that would mean doing this logical operation:

1) cumulative_sum = 5+2+7+4+0+3 = 21

2) 68% of cumulative_sum =  14.28

3) then start summing: 7+5+4+... and select the relative elements, just until they exceed 14.28 (in this simplified example this would select only the values 7 and 5)

4) Of the selected elements, I need to get the coordinates in the array `a`
(in this case, `(1,0)` and `(0,0)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done using a simple `for` loop to iterate over the (coordinate, value) pairs in `b`. The trick is to test if the sum would overflow the desired limit *before* we add the coordinate tuple `t` to the list of coordinates in `selected`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[5,2],[7,4],[0,3]]

b = [((i, j), v) for i, t in enumerate(a) for j, v in enumerate(t)]
b.sort(key=itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
coords, vals = zip(*b)

total = sum(vals)
lim = int(0.68 * total)

selected = []
s = 0
for t, v in b:
    if s + v <= lim:
        s += v
        selected.append(t)
    else:
        break

print(s, selected)
```

**output**

```
12 [(1, 0), (0, 0)]
```

The limit calculation *could* be written as

```
lim = 0.68 * total
```

but if your data is guaranteed to be integers then it's neater to have `lim` as an integer too, because comparing 2 integers is slightly more efficient than comparing an integer to a float. When you do an operation combining an int with a float (and that includes comparisons) they have to be converted to a common type to perform the operation.

---

Here's an alternative version, as discussed in the comments. It loops over the values in `vals` until the desired sum is reached, keeping track of the index in `vals`. It then uses that index to slice the used values and corresponding coordinate tuples from the `b` list into the new `selected` list (which is different to the `selected` list of the previous version).

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[5, 2], [7, 4], [0, 3]]

b = [((i, j), v) for i, t in enumerate(a) for j, v in enumerate(t)]
b.sort(key=itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
coords, vals = zip(*b)

lim = 0.68 * sum(vals)

s = 0
for i, v in enumerate(vals):
    if s + v <= lim:
        s += v
    else:
        break

selected = b[:i]
print(i, selected)

for (i, j), v in selected:
    print(i, j, v)
```

**output**

```
2 [((1, 0), 7), ((0, 0), 5)]
1 0 7
0 0 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Luckily my data are not integers, actually they are very small numbers, therefore I should not use lim as an integer.

Comment: How can I extract those pairs of coordinates, I mean how can I arrange the code such that it automatically stores a[1][0] and a[0][0] (as in the example, but generally all the values that contribute to the 68% of the total sum) in a new list?

Comment: @johnhenry You can do it just the same way that we save the coordinate into the `selected` list.  Outside the loop initialize an empty list, eg `values = []`. Then inside the loop do `values.append(v)` just before or just after the `selected.append(t)` line.

Comment: Thanks although my problem is a bit more complicated than that. In practice I have to plot the values a[1][0] and a[0][0], associated to their coordinates on a grid. The tuples that your solution is outputting are creating difficulties for me, as I am not able to use them again to pick array elements to be sent to plotting

Comment: @johnhenry Sorry, I don't quite understand the problem. If you have a coordinate tuple eg `t = (2, 1)` you can do `a[t[0]][t[1]]` to get `a[2][1]`. But you don't need to do that if you create the `values` list described in my previous comment since each item in that list corresponds to the coordinate tuples in the `selected` list. Another option is to modify the code in my answer so that it just finds the index in the `b` array that corresponds to the end of the selected components. I'll add some more code to explain what I mean.